# Redirect Urls with Wordpress Variables

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to change the permalink structure of my website from

../%postname%/

to

.. /%categroy%/%postname%/

The problem is that there are many backlinks which still link to /%postname%/ and those would return a 404. I tried using plugins but they wont let me use the variables from wordpress.

Now, I want to create a redirect for all those old Backlinks which redirect from

../%postname%/

to

.. /%categroy%/%postname%/

I guess an easy solution would be to modify the htaccess file but I have no idea how to do this? Or are there actually any plugins which handle that problem? 
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can not add info using simple rewriting that isn’t there in the first place. The server has no way of knowing based on `postname` alone, what the correct _category_ would be. This should rather be handled by a script, that gets all those requests, that match the “postname only” pattern, rewritten to it, and can then take that post name and go look up the details of that post in the database, to construct the proper URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

you may check this plugin this will help for variable redirect for users 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/